# How to make Qt subwidget height equal?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt4, qdockwidget

I have some `QDockWidget`s (not floating, only closable) inside a single `QWidget`.
I have some widgets inside each `QDockWidget` - their heights should be equal.
These inner widgets can be hidden through the context menu.

My inner widgets should have equal height. I done it this way:

```
void MyDocksPanel::redistributeSpace()
{
    QBoxLayout * lay = (QBoxLayout *)layout();
    for (int i = 0; i < lay->count(); i++)
    {
        QWidget * dock = lay->itemAt(i)->widget();
        if (dock == NULL)
            continue;

        int size = 0;
        foreach(QWidget * subWidget, dock->findChildren<QWidget*>())
            size += subWidget->isVisible() ? 1 : 0;

        if (dock->isVisible() && (size == 0))
            dock->hide();
        lay->setStretch(i, size);
    }
}
```

All works fine until I add some const elements to each `QDockWidget`: some horizontal scrollbars and some Labels... Now my inner widgets have different sizes. But it is necessary for me to set their heights strongly equal.

`QLayout` lays out widget sizes on one level of a widget's hierarchy. How can I make height-equal subwidgets?

3 subwidgets vs 2 subwidgets

[image: First picture]

My first strategy to set stretches 3 and 2:

[image]

But, when i have added scroll bars:

[image]

Heights of my 5 widgets are equals to 37,37,37,28,28 ... and thats the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track with the stretch factors, but think in terms of pixel values rather than small proportions. Try setting the stretch factor of each dock widget to this:

```
dockWidgetStretch = numChildWidgets * childWidgetMinimumHeight + scrollBarHeight;
```

where `childWidgetMinimumHeight` and `scrollBarHeight` are both expressed in pixels, and are both constants.

EDIT: Here is a working example. You might have to experiment a bit to get it to work with your program, but this should be a good start.

header.h

```
#include <QtGui>

class WidgetWith3Children : public QWidget
{
public:
    WidgetWith3Children()
    {
        QTextEdit *edit1 = new QTextEdit;
        QTextEdit *edit2 = new QTextEdit;
        QTextEdit *edit3 = new QTextEdit;
        QScrollBar *scrollBar = new QScrollBar(Qt::Horizontal);
        QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
        layout->addWidget(edit1);
        layout->addWidget(edit2);
        layout->addWidget(edit3);
        layout->addWidget(scrollBar);
        setLayout(layout);
    }
};

class WidgetWith2Children : public QWidget
{
public:
    WidgetWith2Children()
    {
        QTextEdit *edit1 = new QTextEdit;
        QTextEdit *edit2 = new QTextEdit;
        QScrollBar *scrollBar = new QScrollBar(Qt::Horizontal);
        QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
        layout->addWidget(edit1);
        layout->addWidget(edit2);
        layout->addWidget(scrollBar);
        setLayout(layout);
    }
};

class OuterWidget : public QWidget
{
public:
    OuterWidget()
    {
        QDockWidget *dockWidget1 = new QDockWidget;
        QDockWidget *dockWidget2 = new QDockWidget;
        dockWidget1->setWidget(new WidgetWith3Children);
        dockWidget2->setWidget(new WidgetWith2Children);
        QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;

        // 71 is the height of the minimum size hint for QTextEdit
        // 30 is the height of a horizontal scrollbar (on my system)
        layout->addWidget(dockWidget1, 71 * 3 + 30);
        layout->addWidget(dockWidget2, 71 * 2 + 30);

        layout->setMargin(0);
        setLayout(layout);
    }
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "header.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    OuterWidget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Should I also add QDockWidget's header height and margin*2 and spacing between subitems and scrollbar?

Comment: My guess is yes, you should. :) But try it without doing that, and see if it works.

Comment: Two days ago i've tried this way. No success. I'll try again tomorrow. And i have problem with childWidgetMinimumHeight - i would like to resize whole widget manually...

Comment: No, today i can't do it. Only tomorrow. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just to check I understand: you have a `QDockWidget` which contains multiple children, as well as a label and a horizontal scrollbar. The label and scrollbar should be of fixed height, and the remaining vertical space should be divided between the child widgets.

If that's correct, all you need to do is add a `QVBoxLayout` to each `QDockWidget`. Add your widgets as I've done below:

```
QDockWidget DockWidget;
QVBoxLayout Layout = new QVBoxLayout(DockWidget);

FixedHeightWidget.setFixedHeight(10)
Layout.addWidget(FixedHeightWidget, 0);
Layout.addWidget(FirstVariableHeightWidget, 1);
Layout.addWidget(SecondVariableHeightWidget, 1);
Layout.addWidget(ThirdVariableHeightWidget, 1);
```

If you were to hide any of the widgets you've added to the layout, the layout will handle resizing the remaining visible children.

Comment: All right, but i have multiple QDockWidgets int QVBoxLayout. And whole by subwidgets should have equal sizes.

Comment: Sorry dude, not sure I understand what you mean there! Could you explain a bit further? An image of some sort would be really useful here.

Comment: I have 3-4 QDockWidgets in QVBoxLayout with 1-5 children widgets in each (using QVBoxLayout too). Children widgets should have equal sizes.

Comment: If you're adding the children to the `QVBoxLayout` as I have above (note that I have supplied a stretch factor of `1` for each child), they should each be given an equal amount of the space that remains in the layout **after** the space for any fixed-size widgets has been allocated. However, if any of your variable size widgets has a `minimumSize` larger than this, the layout will attempt to give them the height they need. As I say, a screenshot of what your widgets currently look like, along with an explanation of what's wrong would be very useful here.

Comment: A have just added a lot of screenshots. It's really problem. Maybe creating own MagicLayout can help?